# Mocking presenter cause integration test to dump

Tags: android, integration-testing, android-junit

Recently i've started covering my project with integration tests where mockito provides presenter instances to verify whether or not my views calling presenter methods properly during their events.

The issue was on the screen which has invisible `ProgressBar` and `RecyclerView`. Presenter of that screen have been loading data for that `RecyclerView` and controlling visibility of `ProgressBar`. When i replaced it with mock (used Mockito) it caused corresponding tests to totally stuck with error after a while:

```
Could not launch intent Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x14000000 
cmp=com.example.kinopoisk/com.example.mvp.view.activity.MainActivity } within 45 seconds. 
Perhaps the main thread has not gone idle within a reasonable amount of time? 
There could be an animation or something constantly repainting the screen. 
Or the activity is doing network calls on creation? See the threaddump logs. 
For your reference the last time the event queue was idle before your activity launch request 
was 1476191336691 and now the last time the queue went idle was: 1476191336691. 
If these numbers are the same your activity might be hogging the event queue
```

But activity was successfully running and was accessible for all user events like clicks etc.

How do you think, what cause a problem?

*This is a question for community knowledge base only, i've found answer myself*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation is in that line of error code: **There could be an animation or something constantly repainting the screen.**

When i had replaced presenter with mockito's one, it stopped controlling progress bar as well. The initial state of it was `View.VISIBLE`, so that was cause test to hadn't been able to connect.

The solution was just set initial state of `ProgressBar` to `View.GONE`, but found it was a bit of headache for me.